# Real part of inner product is greater than the smaller norm in closed convex subset of a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Suppose $V$ is a Hilbert space, $U$ is is a nonempty closed convex subset of $V$, and $g ∈ U$ is the unique element of $U$ with smallest norm. Prove that $\operatorname{Re}\langle g,h\rangle ≥ ‖‖^2$, for all $h ∈ U$.

I tried to use "convex": $tg+(1-t)h ∈ U$ for all $h ∈ U$, and $‖tg+(1-t)h‖ ≥ ‖‖$ as $g$ is the smallest. But cannot prove the inequality. Am I in the right way? Any help?

Answer (score 1):

$\def\Re{\operatorname{Re}}$Here's an idea. Suppose that you have $\Re\langle h,g\rangle<\|g\|^2$ for some $h\in U$. Then, for $t\in(0,1)$ (the important thing is that $t>0$),
\begin{align}
\|tg+(1-t)h\|^2&=t^2\|g\|^2+(1-t)^2\|h\|^2+2t(1-t)\,\operatorname{Re}\langle g,h\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&<t^2\|g\|^2+(1-t)^2\|h\|^2+2t(1-t)\,\|g\|^2\\[0.3cm]
&\leq t^2\|g\|^2+(1-t)^2\|g\|^2+2t(1-t)\,\|g\|^2\\[0.3cm]
&=\|g\|^2,
\end{align}
giving us a contradiction.